# Customising scroll view action inside cameraX library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface

I’ve doubt regarding UI in android studio
Got a task and need to achieve it
Here I’m mentimoning my problem description as follows :
— i want to create custom camera how Snapchat and Instagram works

- in that I need to know specific design where the scroll between filters in their custom camera

I’ve created my custom cameraX library and tried using viewpager,horizon table scroll view , custom guesture detection
Nothing works out